# JQuery: Append before an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using JQuery I have appended a div into a container called `.mobile-sub`. I call the append by doing:

```
$('.s2_error').addClass("revive");
$('.revive').parent(".mobile-sub").append('<div>mydiv</div>');
```

It works fine but the problem is that it is placing the div **after** the `.s2_error` tag whereas I need it to be placed **before** so the end result HTML will look like this:

```
<div>mydiv</div>
<p class="s2_error">Error</p>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Using various options like below

**insertBefore**

```
$("<div>mydiv</div>").insertBefore('.mobile-sub .s2_error');
```

OR by writing another selector inside your `insertBefore`

```
$("<div>mydiv</div>").insertBefore($('.revive').parent(".mobile-sub").find('.s2_error'));
```

Meaning

`$('thisElementShouldBe').insertBefore('thisElement');`

---

**prepend**

```
$('.revive').parent(".mobile-sub").prepend('<div>mydiv</div>');
```

So `<div>mydiv</div>` will always be **added as the first child** of `mobile-sub`

---

**before**

```
 $('.revive').parent(".mobile-sub").find('.s2_error').before("<div>mydiv</div>");
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer :) `prepend` did exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 9):

You can do it two ways:

1. **Before**

   ```
   $(".s2_error").before("<div>mydiv</div>");
   ```
2. **InsertBefore**

   ```
   $("<div>mydiv</div>").insertBefore(".s2_error");
   ```

Both do the same but they are syntactically different.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.insertBefore()](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/)

> Insert every element in the set of matched elements before the target.

```
$("<div>mydiv</div>").insertBefore('.s2_error');
```

OR, [.before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/)

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, before each element in the set of matched elements.

```
$('.s2_error').before("<div>mydiv</div>");
```

Note: The `.before()` and `.insertBefore()` methods perform the same task. The major difference is in the syntax—specifically, in the placement of the content and target.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add element as first child. You need to use `.prepend()` instead of `.append()`:

```
$('.revive').parent(".mobile-sub").prepend('<div>mydiv</div>');
```

You can also use `.insertBefore ()`:

```
$("<div>mydiv</div>").insertBefore('.s2_error');
```

or `.before()`:

```
$( ".s2_error" ).before( "<div>mydiv</div>" );
```

Comment: Thank you :) I wish I had come across `prepend` before it's really quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
.insertBefore( target )
```

> Description: Insert every element in the set of matched elements
>   before the target.

or

```
.before( content [, content ] )
```

> Description: Insert content, specified by the parameter, before each
>   element in the set of matched elements.